# Having Problems with exporting to fbx

Tags: mesh, objects, export, unity, .fbx

For some reason my Blender Exports doesnt work fine and this is not the first project with this issues some Objects are overlapping, missing or Faces of Objects are visible.
[image]

[image: Here is the exported FBX in Unity and like you see the sign and gate overlap with the building]

[image: Here is the file in Blender and everything normal]

[image: Here is the file in Blender and everything normal]

[image: Here is the exported fbx in Unity and like you see there is missing the front of the car . There is also missing the back of the car]

Comment: hello, typically the kind of problem you can have is inverted normals, have you checked the normals in Blender? Also make sure you don't have overlapping faces or vertices?

Comment: If I flip normals suddenly it's even weirder in Blender nothing overlaps. I have a feeling that extruded planes don't work properly, as well as already accepted Bolean modifiers

Comment: please share one of your dysfonctional object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots I uploaded it there a few days ago, can I see somewhere that it worked?

Comment: Once uploaded you need to share the link here

Comment: @moonboots ok done

Comment: First you need to recalculate the normals (and not Flip Normals): shortcut Shift N. Also, remove the doubles (M > Merge by Distance).